# Why doesn't the html see the new images from the flask route?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to make generate a new image every time I reload the html with Flask.
My html is like this

```
<img src="/getLinearImage" alt="User Image" height="100px" width="100px">
```

Where /getLinearImage is a this:

```
@app.route("/getLinearImage")
def showImageLinear():
    return getImage(getLinearImage())
```

And **getImage()** returns the image with **send_file()** method. When I go to the url and refresh the page the image changes but when the html accesses the page it does not generate a new image on page refresh. Any ideas why that occurs?

Comment: "html accesses the page it does not generate a new image on page refresh"

What does that mean, "html accesses the page"

Comment: To my understanding when a html image has a source that is a flask route it wil go to that route and insert the file. However in this situation it keeps on inserting the cached image without going to the route amd generating a new image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rule out the browser caching the first image, try rewriting

```
return getImage(getLinearImage())
```

as

```
response = getImage(getLinearImage())
response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0'
return response
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. The images were being cached and not accessed by html